# reset file permissions on mac root folder

Tags: macos, security

here is what I have done,

```
    cd /
    chmod 000 .
```

Which has changed my all file permissions.

I can only see the blue screen on my mac and not able to login.

I tried following links with no luck.

```
 1 login as single user mode
  and execute these commands 
 /sbin/mount -uw /
 cd /private/var/db
 rm .AppleSetupDone
 halt
```

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-can-i-fix-permission-issue-when-i-cannot-start-mac-os-x

I don't want to try any random things further, any help would be appreciated.

thanks..!

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452 could help, but this is really better asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what worked for me.

http://macs.about.com/od/faq1/f/emergencystart.htm

in case anybody faces the same problem.